# Third-order PDE and Fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, fourier-series, sturm-liouville

I am wondering how to find a Fourier series solution of the following PDE:

$$u_{t} + i u_{xxx} = 0$$
$$u(0, x) = u_{0}(x)$$

where $t$ is in $(0, \infty)$ and $x$ is in the torus $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z})$, and we assuming $u_{0}$ is represented by its Fourier series (e.g., $u_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ ).

I started with supposing $u(t, x) = X(x)T(t)$ and plugged into the PDE to get that $\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = \frac{-i X'''(x)}{X(x)} = \lambda$, which gives $T'(t) - \lambda T(t) = 0$, hence $T(t) = C_{\lambda}e^{\lambda t}$.

Then we have $u(t, x) = X(x)T(x) = X(x)C_{\lambda}e^{\lambda t}$. Using the initial condition, we get $u(0, x) = X(x)C = u_{0}(x)$.

Then we suppose there is a general solution of the form $u(t, x) = \sum_{\lambda}X_{\lambda}(x)T_{\lambda}(t) = \sum_{\lambda}\frac{1}{C_{\lambda}}u_{0}(x)C_{\lambda}e^{\lambda t} = \sum_{\lambda}u_{0}(x)e^{\lambda t}$.

At this point I am confused as to how to get a Fourier series solution by setting $u(0,x) = u_0 = \sum_{k}a_{k}e^{i k x}$, where the $a_k$ are the Fourier series coefficients of $u_0$. Since the $\lambda$ might not be an integer, but even if we assume $\lambda_k$ is indexed by the integers, then we are saying $u(0, x) = \sum_{\lambda_k}u_{0}(x) = u_0 = \sum_{k}a_{k}e^{ikx}$, and it is not clear to me how to solve for coefficients for $u(t, x)$.

Comment: Typically you need to solve both ODEs for $X$ and $T$ as this will constrain $\lambda$ when you use the boundary conditions arising from periodicity. Another approach could simply be plugging the ansatz $\sum_k c_k(t)e^{ikx}$ into the PDE and solving for the $c_k(t)$ term by term (or taking the inner product of both sides of the PDE with $e^{ikx}$, integrating by parts, and solving for the Fourier coefficients that way)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't see any way of solving the third-order ODE directly. On the other hand the ansatz idea is interesting but isn't this more restrictive than the usual approach of assuming the solution is a series $\sum_{k}X_{k}(t)T_{k}(t)$, after solving for eigenfunctions? That is, we should get some kind of solution but I am worried it is less general than the solution gotten from separation of variables. @kieransquared

Comment: Given that you specify the initial data, what do you mean by less general? If you’re looking for a solution which can be written as a Fourier series, this is how you would find one. You can check that the $c_k(t)$ are precisely the Fourier coefficients $\hat{u}(k,t)$ which satisfy the ODE $\hat{u}_t+k^3\hat{u}=0$, which is obtained by taking the Fourier transform of the equation.

Comment: The latter approach (taking the Fourier transform and solving the resulting ODE) is arguably more “rigorous”, but they’re essentially equivalent